# Spring Cloud Eureka in Standalone Mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

This [link](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_standalone_mode) clearly mentions which properties are required in order to have a Eureka Server working in Standalone mode (without Replicas).

I understand all these properties except why we need the following one (in order to have the server in Standalone Mode): `eureka.instance.hostname`

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The property `eureka.instance.hostname` determine if your server discovery could be running in another customized hostname:port